# Can i get only the img from a database field where different html tags are used?

Tags: php, image

I have this php array. Where in my database i have a field called body, and in that field there is some html code. Like this:

```
   <h1>title</h1><img src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4075/4788694752_d03557765b_z.jpg" alt=""/>
```

Here is my php code:

```
                 <?php

                $q = "SELECT * FROM journals ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

                while($journal_list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { ?>
                     <div class="col-md-4">

                <a class="list-group-item" href="journal.php?id=<?php echo $journal_list['id']; ? >">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><?php echo $journal_list['body']; ´?></h4>                    
                </a>    
                </div>

            <?php } ?>
```

In the h4 im calling the body field in the database.   But i only want the img in that field??

Comment: You could use a DOM parser to obtain the img.

Comment: I don't have any experience with that.  But i will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hack that you can use

```
$img = explode('img',$journal['body']);
$final_img = '<img '.$img[1];
```

Now echo image as

```
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><?php echo $final_img; ?></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [phpquery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/):

```
$src = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($journal_list['body'])->find('img')->attr('src');
```

Comment: Amazing :) I'll look into this too.